# is big GROUP_CONCAT efficient and how to get around it?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i have queries like this

```
SELECT
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c) FROM t1) AS t1c,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c) FROM t2) AS t2c,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c) FROM t3) AS t3c
```

each of `t(1/2/3)c` values are above the `group_concat_max_len` by a lot that it reaches above default value by quadrable the amount

my head only thinks of running multiple queries

```
SELECT c FROM t1;
SELECT c FROM t2;
SELECT c FROM t3;
```

and binding each to an array and imploding them so i wonder if there is a way to mimick `group_concat` instead of looping in php if it is slower.

Comment: you should test that running a loop in mysql which concatinates all values in a huge TEXT datatype against the php version, but i doobt that any of that will ever be efficient in any way. imade such a thing with javascript, so that the server would have the load. Aölso php has always a time limit

Comment: @nbk would using the group_concat despite reaching high length be faster than multiple  query and while loops?

Comment: Group_concat at that dimensions is slow. try it out.

Comment: Change `group_concat_max_len` for your session to be big enough.  Assuming that is not more than, say, 10% of RAM. your task should run fine.  It will be reasonably fast.